# Left join acts as inner join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, outer-join

I have the following Query:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT t.productid as Prod_id,
   EXTRACT(week from t.dt) as WEEK,
   COUNT(pv.productid) as PageViews,
   COUNT(t.productid) as orders, 
   COUNT(t.productid)/COUNT(DISTINCT(pv.loadid)) as Conversion,
   AVG(t.price) avg_price,
   MAX(pv.numreviews) max_numreviews,
   MIN(pv.numreviews) min_numreviews,
   AVG(pv.numreviews) avg_numreviews,
   COUNT( DISTINCT pv.bvsid ) sessions
   FROM PageView pv LEFT OUTER JOIN Transaction t ON t.productid = pv.productid 
   AND t.dt BETWEEN '2014-06-06' AND '2014-06-18' AND ( lower(t.currency) = 'usd' OR lower(t.country) IN ('us', 'usa', 'united states') )
   WHERE pv.dt BETWEEN '2014-06-06' AND '2014-06-18'
   AND pv.client ='abc' AND lower(pv.type) = 'product'
   GROUP BY WEEK, Prod_id
   ORDER BY WEEK asc;
```

Which gives the values for PageViews and Orders as same, basically taking only the common productid's. I want the correct values of Pageviews and Orders and would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT productId...` should be unnecessary, given you have a matching `GROUP BY`.  Query dates [with an exclusive upper bound (`<`)](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  `Transaction` shouldn't store user-entered data: you should canonicalize `currency` and `country` (no need for `LOWER(...)`).  The use of `WEEK(...)` will ignore indices; if you use a range table (either via a Calendar table or generated as part of your query) you can use one.

Answer (score 3):

The expressions:

```
COUNT(pv.productid) as PageViews,
COUNT(t.productid) as orders,
```

count the non-NULL values of the two fields.  If they are the same, then all the records match.  However, I suspect that you want:

```
COUNT(pv.productid) as PageViews,
COUNT(distinct t.productid) as orders,
```

Also, you shouldn't use `select distinct` when you have a `group by` clause.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Doing Count(distinct t.productid) just gives value '1' for each productid, which is incorrect.